# The multi-linear maps are prone to zeroizing attack. Can anyone explain how the zeroizing attack breaks the computational assumptions?

Tags: pairings

I read that many cryptographic schemes based on multi-linear mapping are not secure because the zero testing procedure and zero encoding help an adversary to reveal the secrets and because of it, many computational assumptions are solved in the multi-linear pairing. For example, the DDH assumption is solved in the bilinear pairing. In that way, is there any explanation which can show why the multi-linear pairing is not secure.